# Why is current shared in a parallel circuit but not a series circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Electricity test coming up. It's not clear to me why current is shared in a parallel circuit but not a series circuit.

Comment: This 'question' does not show *any* research effort.

Answer (score 1):

All the electrons in a series circuit only have one place to go. So every electron that goes through (say) the first resistor also has to go through the second.

But if two resistors are in parallel, the electron has a "choice". It's like cars and roads - if there is one road from A to B and another from B to C, then every car has to drive on both those roads to get from A to C (series). But if there are two different roads from A to C, some cars will take one road and other cars will take the other.